# Use of `periodic` in NetWire 5

Tags: haskell, netwire

Consider the following code:

```
-- this defines what our 'state' will be
data Direction = North | East | South | West deriving (Eq, Show, Enum)
data State = State Int Bool Direction deriving (Show)

initialState :: State
initialState = State 0 True North

-- a simple routine to change a state and count the number of
-- changes
nextState :: State -> State
nextState (State i _ West) = State (i+1) False South
nextState (State i _ North) = State (i+1) True East
nextState (State i b s) = State i b $ (if b then succ else pred) s

-- a wire with local state
stateWire :: Wire s () m a State
stateWire = stateWireFrom initialState
  where
    stateWireFrom s = mkSFN $ \_ -> (nextState s, stateWireFrom (nextState s))

-- let's run the wire!
main = testWire clockSession_ stateWire
```

As you can imagine, `testWire` will run the wire as fast as it can and print the output to screen. But what if I want to run my wire every 2 seconds? Looking at the docs, `periodic` may be the solution:

```
-- Since periodic generates events, asSoonAs is used to 'unwrap' the Event
main = testWire clockSession_ (asSoonAs . periodic 2 . stateWire)
```

This **almost** works. The output seems to be static for about 2 seconds, but when it's updated, it's clear that the wire were running while the output was stopped. Maybe I should do the other way around?

```
-- Now, this does make more sense to me...
main = testWire clockSession_ (stateWire . periodic 2)
```

However, the end result is exactly like my first try. What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28839272/851863) for a (inferior) alternative to the accepted answer.

Comment: I'd recommend you to post your edit as an answer instead; Answering your own questions is permitted on stackoverflow and makes more sense than putting the answer into the question. Also, there's probably no need to replicate my answer, unless you want to emphasize some difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you treat your  `stateWire` as if it was a continuous wire, but it really should be an event wire itself. Assuming I understood your intent correctly, it should probably be `accumE (flip $ const nextState) initialState` - see [the event docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire-5.0.1/docs/Control-Wire-Event.html) for accumE - then you can use it like this:

`stateWire . periodic 2` (the other way round would not work).

The reason why your original version doesn't work is that `periodic` doesn't inhibit when there's no event, it instead just produces a `NoEvent` value. And since your stateWire just ignores its input, whether or not an event is produced doesn't make any difference to it when the periodic wire is in front, whereas putting the periodic wire in the back just means 'periodically catch a snapshot of the current state', which is also not what you want.

*Note*: 'Front' and 'back' in the previous paragraph refer to the order of execution, not to the layout in source code which is in reverse if you use the `.` combinator.

Comment: I guess you mean `accumE (flip $ const nextState) initialState`. This works, but it made me realize that I can make it work with a continuous wire if I filter it with `when occurred`.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. Fixed now.

That requires Unsafe.Event and IMHO a state change that depends on an event is (should be) certainly an event itself. Doing it like that you suddenly get a wire that claims to be continuous, but actually doesn't produce values for any interval.

Comment: You're right. Thinking in events really seems the correct way to model this problem. Also, edited my question according to your feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, it's also possible to filter out the `NoEvent`, without changing the wire:

```
main = testWire clockSession_ (stateWire . when occurred . periodic 2)
```

In this case, the wire will change the state, **inhibit for 2 seconds** and then change it again.

The other (accepted) answer works different: the wire will change the state, then **continue producing the same result for 2 seconds** and then change it again.